# Point annotation manager drag and drop delegate method missing

Tags: mapbox-ios

I want to detect the point annotation drag and drop movement on the map. But in v10.14.0 point annotation delegates and listeners are missing, to detect the drag coordinate of annotation.

PointAnnotation Manager provides only one delegate Annotation Interaction Delegate to detect the Tap on marker. But it will also not work after dragging maker on map.

Mapbox marker documentation: https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/annotations/

**Code snippet**

`let pointAnnotationManager = mapView.annotations.makePointAnnotationManager() pointAnnotationManager.delegate = self                                          pointAnnotationManager.annotations = annotations                                pointAnnotationManager.iconAllowOverlap = false`

AnnotationInteractionDelegate should work after dragging annotation.